# Proxy in Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to create a Chrome Extension wich changes the Proxy Settings of Chrome.
Everything works correct but the problem is that i have to authenticate with username and password with the proxy.

Any idea how to do this ?

```
          var config = {
    mode: "fixed_servers",
    rules: {
      proxyForHttp: {
  scheme: "https",
  host: "209.164.75.72",
  port: 9786,
  username:'myusernmae',
  password:'proxypassword'

      },
      bypassList: ["foobar.com"]
    }
  };
  chrome.proxy.settings.set(
      {value: config, scope: 'regular'},
      function() {
    console.debug(chrome);    

          });
```

The above code doesnt work as seen here there are no valid documentation how to authenticate the proxy 
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/proxy

Answer (score 1):

You can listen for [`chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#event-onAuthRequired) to provide the credentials when `details.isProxy` is true. You'll need the `webRequest` and `webRequestBlocking` permissions.

That's how [Chrome-proxy-helper](https://github.com/henices/Chrome-proxy-helper) works.

Comment: I want to set the Proxy when chrome starts no need for editional browser buttons.