# How to obtain the system proxy settings from chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, proxy

I need to make a customized proxy settings for my chrome extension so that traffic to a specific domain goes through a proxy server while all other (user) traffic goes normally with the default system settings. According to the chrome API documentation, the only way is to use pac_script (correct me if I am wrong). Thus, the code will be something like this:

```
var config = {
mode: "pac_script",
pacScript: {
data: "function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {\n" +
    "  if (dnsDomainIs(host, 'mydomain.com') )\n" +
    "    return 'SOCKS5 10.0.0.1:1234';\n" +
    "  return 'DIRECT';\n" +
    "}"
}};
chrome.proxy.settings.set({value: config, scope: 'regular'});
```

However, pac_script does not have the option to route traffic using system proxy settings (only 'DIRECT' which means it will skip the system settings). I thought to obtain the system proxy settings using `chrome.proxy.settings.get`, but this function returns an object where `mode = system` with no useful information.

Does anyone know how to obtain the system proxy settings from extension? Or has suggestions to handle the original problem?

Comment: Based on the related [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26187895) that I found about your issue, they also use [chrome.proxy](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/proxy) for the proxy settings in chrome extension and it is the official API for it. If you found out that pac_script does not have the option to route traffic, then it means that this is not supported with it. I suggest you to ask this question on [Chrome extension Groups](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!forum/chromium-extensions) so that an expert in Chrome extension can help you with this issue.

Answer (score 4):

You can get it with

```
chrome.proxy.settings.get(
      {'incognito': false},
      function(config) {
          console.log(JSON.stringify(config));
      });
```

It should show you something like this:

```
{
  "levelOfControl":"controlled_by_this_extension",
  "value":
   {
    "mode":"pac_script",
    "pacScript": {
                   "data": "function FindProxyForURL(url, host) {\n     
                               return \"PROXY 10.0.0.1:1234;\";\n}",
                   "mandatory": false
     }
    }
}
```

Read the doc for more detailed
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/proxy